# MacBook Pro won’t sleep automatically — no process preventing sleep according to pmset. What’s going on?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, macos

i noticed the following problem with my MBP 8,1 running 10.7.2 — automatic sleep just *doesn’t happen*. Since I usually put my Macbook to sleep manually before leaving the desk etc. I just noticed this issue and can’t really pinpoint it to specific updates.

What happens automatically is display sleep. Computer sleep just doesn’t occur.

Closing the lid works, selecting “sleep” from the Apple menu works. The only way to put my MBP to sleep automatically is currently PleaseSleep, which works fine.

Here’s pmset -g:

```
pmset -g 
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay   4200
 standby    0
 womp       1
 halfdim    1
 panicrestart   157680000
 hibernatefile  /var/vm/sleepimage
 sms        1
 networkoversleep   0
 disksleep  10
 sleep      10
 hibernatemode  3
 ttyskeepawake  1
 displaysleep   3
 acwake     0
 lidwake    1
```

As you can see, no process is preventing sleep.

Here’s pmset -g assertions:

```
pmset -g assertions
25.12.11 03:05:34 MEZ   
Assertion status system-wide:
   ChargeInhibit                           0
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep             0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep              0
   NoRealPowerSources_debug                0
   CPUBoundAssertion                       0
   EnableIdleSleep                         1
   PreventSystemSleep                      0
   DisableInflow                           0
   DisableLowPowerBatteryWarnings          0
   ExternalMedia                           0

Kernel Assertions: 0x0004 
 * Kernel Assertion ID = 500
   Created At = 01.01.70 01:03:17 MEZ   
   Modified At = 25.12.11 02:46:14 MEZ   
   Owner ID = 0xffffff800b664000
   Level = 255
   Assertions Set = None (4)

 * Kernel Assertion ID = 501
   Created At = 01.01.70 01:03:21 MEZ   
   Modified At = 01.01.70 01:00:00 MEZ   
   Owner ID = 0xffffff800b674000
   Level = 0
   Assertions Set = None (4)

 * Kernel Assertion ID = 502
   Created At = 01.01.70 01:05:31 MEZ   
   Modified At = 25.12.11 02:38:13 MEZ   
   Owner ID = 0xffffff800b704200
   Level = 0
   Assertions Set = None (32)
```

Any ideas? I tried resetting the SMC, to no avail.

Bluetooth is off, Sharing is off. Automatic sleep doesn’t occur both on power adapter and battery power. Unplugging USB hub with things like keyboard/mouse connected makes no difference.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** Just booted into safe mode, and automatic sleep definitely works then.

**EDIT 2** After removing Google Software Update, automatic sleep miraculously started working again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pmset.  What are you expecting it to show when sleep is being prevented?  I have Caffeine turned on right now and the output from my pmset looks almost exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Have you tried setting the computer sleep time in System Perferences > Energy Saver to something else? Say 5 minutes? Sometimes manually sliding the bar triggers the proper event again.

Comment: i have exactly some problem with you?
and check the process 500, 501, 502 but there is no process running

Comment: @MitchLindgren It should look something like this:

`sleep 0 (imposed by %processnumber)`

http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/osx_lion_pmset_shows_app_imposed_sleep/

Comment: @cksum Yes, I tried setting computer sleep to 1 and 2 minutes.

Comment: @ade I don’t think these are process numbers.

Comment: Look what happens when I do pmset noidle in the terminal, a command preventing idle sleep:

`pmset -g 
Active Profiles:
Battery Power  1
AC Power  -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay 4200
 standby 0
 womp  1
 halfdim 1
 panicrestart 157680000
 hibernatefile /var/vm/sleepimage
 sms  1
 networkoversleep 0
 disksleep 10
 sleep  0 (imposed by 967)
 hibernatemode 3
 ttyskeepawake 1
 displaysleep 3
 acwake  0
 lidwake 1`

pid 967, not surprisingly, points to pmset.

Comment: With Caffeine turned on I get `sleep 30` in pmset, so it doesn't look like that's a reliable way to determine which processes may be preventing sleep.  I occasionally experience problems with sleep not happening correctly, but I haven't been able to sort them out.  Usually I just reboot and then the problem will go away for a while.

Comment: Did you test in between safe boot and uninstall of Google SU?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Bluetooth turned on and if so, in the advanced tab of the bluetooth preference panel to you have the checkbox checked that allows bluetooth devices to wake your computer?

I had a similar problem and found that my magic mouse was preventing hibernation with the lid open.

Comment: Bluetooth is off, no Magic Mouse or other bluetooth peripherals.

Comment: Wake for network access checkbox in Energy Saver?

Comment: Doesn’t help — no automatic sleep, no matter if “Wake for network access” is checked or not. Just found out though that in Safe Mode, automatic sleep works. A 3rd party app or extension has to cause this.

Answer (score 1):

I made two changes:

- Disallowed bluetooth devices to wake up computer;
- Uninstalled google notifier.

Now the computer will sleep