# pmset standby is missing

Tags: macos

I have two Macbook Pros (10.7.2) and both are missing the standby option in pmset:

```
$ pmset -g
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 womp       1
 halfdim    1
 sms        1
 panicrestart   157680000
 gpuswitch  2
 hibernatefile  /var/vm/sleepimage
 networkoversleep   0
 disksleep  10
 sleep      180
 hibernatemode  3
 ttyskeepawake  1
 displaysleep   10
 acwake     0
 lidwake    1

$ pmset -g cap
Capabilities for AC Power:
 displaysleep
 disksleep
 sleep
 womp
 acwake
 lidwake
 halfdim
 sms
 gpuswitch
```

I've seen this guy has this option:[lion pmset standby](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34589/macbook-pro-wont-sleep-automatically-no-process-preventing-sleep-according-to)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the pmset man page:

> STANDBY ARGUMENTS
>
> *standby* causes kernel power management to automatically hibernate a
>   machine after it has slept for a specified time period. This saves power
>   while asleep. This setting defaults to ON for supported hardware. **The
>   setting standby will be visible in pmset -g if the feature is supported
>   on this machine.**
>
> standby only works if hibernation is turned on to hibernatemode 3 or 25.
>
> *standbydelay* specifies the delay, in seconds, before writing the hiberna-
>   tion image to disk and powering off memory for Standby."

The bold text is my highlight.  This would indicate that the two Macbook Pros you're using do not support the standby arguments.

For a list of machines that support standby mode, see [HT4392](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392).

I hope this is helpful.