# macOS Sierra on external drive – Mac do not go to sleep anymore

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, sleep-wake, external-disk

Since two days I am using an external SSD as system disk (to work with my system on my iMac or on my new arriving MacBook Pro – on demand – without any synchronization process). Just attach the disk and boot my system.

On my iMac this work pretty good. I have tested my Thunderbold 2 case – wich was faster on boot as the USB 3.0 case. But the Thunderbold case need external power – so thats not perfect.

Now I am using the USB 3.0 case just connected via USB. And this morning I noticed, that my iMac didn't went to sleep – just the dispay turned off. So the system will not go to sleep automatically. After 5 minutes with turned off display I can still see some flashing LED on the SSD case – once a minute or something.

What can I do to get my system automatically to sleep again?

[image]

Update:

Running `pmset -g` in Terminal, I get the following

```
Currently in use: 
standby               1 
Sleep On Power Button 1 
womp                  0 
halfdim               1 
hibernatefile         /var/vm/sleepimage 
powernap              0 
autorestart           0 
networkoversleep      0 
disksleep             0 
sleep                 1 (sleep prevented by backupd, backupd, UserEventAgent) 
autopoweroffdelay     28800 
hibernatemode         0 
autopoweroff          1 
ttyskeepawake         1 
displaysleep          1 
standbydelay          10800
```

Comment: Could you include in your question a screen capture of `System preferences > Energy Saver > Power Adapter` so as to get better answers?

Comment: Edited. But german. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It won't go to sleep because it can't.**

There's a process (or processes) preventing your system from going to sleep.  `pmset -g` tells us:

> `(sleep prevented by backupd, backupd, UserEventAgent)`

- `backupd` is the Time Machine backup daemon which more than likely is backing up to a USB drive.
- UserEventAgent is a processes that manages high level events that `launchd` doesn't manage - this could be any number of things.

To put the machine to sleep you will need to disable Time Machine and resolve whatever process `UserEventAgent` is attached to (it may be Time Machine itself).

Comment: And why is it possible to get the iMac sleeping when manually activating the sleep mode (via the Apple logo top left). Is it possible to create a small script that detects "no mouse movement" or "copy actions" for X seconds (like the system itself) and put the iMac via Shell script or something into sleep mode.

Comment: Is it actually being put to sleep or is the display just being put into low power mode?

Comment: It is in sleep. The LED on mouse and SSD goes off after a few seconds. My server (which is checking for network availablility via bash script) turns off after 5 minutes if iMac not reachable. So yes, it seems to be in sleep mode.

Comment: `Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 womp                 0
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 autorestart          0
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by backupd, backupd, UserEventAgent)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         1
 standbydelay         10800`

actually is TM backup running.

Comment: Now I disabled automatic TM backup and aborted the acutal backup and everything got to sleep. Hmm. :-) Doing the backup now and will test it again after that.

Comment: TM was the "problem". After starting a completely new TM backup and finishing it the iMac went to sleep as well :-) Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have "Prevent computer from sleeping..." activated in Energy Saver preferences.
[image]

Comment: No. I have unchecked all four checkboxes. And checking "put harddisk to sleep when possible" also do not change anything.

Comment: Do you have a blanck screensaver activated?

Comment: I have the default screensaver activated. It appears, then after a few minutes the display turns off but the iMac do not go really to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of reasons a Mac won’t sleep on the Sierra versions of the os. Have a look at the details and diagnostics that `pmset` command provides:

- [MacBook Pro won’t sleep automatically — no process preventing sleep according to pmset. What’s going on?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34589/macbook-pro-won-t-sleep-automatically-no-process-preventing-sleep-according-to)

In many cases it’s software like google notifier that prevent sleep by design or software like google software update that run a process that often will then block sleep since it’s regularly downloading and updating in the background and hanging around until chrome relaunches.